# Is there a way to do the google did you mean in linq?

Tags: asp.net, linq

I have list of words.  I type in a word misspelled.  Can I query the list using linq to get words that sounds like (soundex) the misspelled word?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can.

A quick google search came up with [this link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/linqprojectgeneral/thread/65deeb8d-af42-4a8b-a860-a2c52aeae545/):

Code Snippet

```
from elt in SomeTable.AsEnumerable()

where SoundEx(elt.SomeWordsSoundExCode) == SoundEx("MyWord")

select elt;
```

Comment: this is for linq to sql not linq to objects?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use LINQ to SQL to query database, then you'll probably want to run the comparison on SQL side. You could use `AsEnumerable`, but then you'll need to implement the algorithm in C# and process the data in-memory.

I believe that LINQ to SQL doesn't provide any built-in method that would be translated to a call to the `SOUNDEX` function in SQL. However, you can add mapping for a user-defined SQL function (See for example [this article](http://blog.benhall.me.uk/2008/05/linq-to-sql-stored-procedure-vs.html)). So, you could define your SQL function that performs the comparison and then write something like:

```
var db = new MyDatabaseContext();
var q = from w in db.Products
        where db.SimilarSoundEx(w.Name, searchInput)
        select w;
```